# Camundongo vs rato!

Tags: significado, português-brasileiro, uso-de-palavras, diferenças

Eu tenho uma questáo um pouco estranha!

*Camundongo* é diferente de *rato*?

Pelo que eu percebi procurando na internet, *camundongo* é aquele que está morando em casas. Mas se sim, por que quando uma pessoa vê esse animal em casa grita *RATO*?

Comment: Esta pergunta me parece ser mais apropriada à SE Biology.

Comment: Gramaticalmente falando, não.

Comment: Pelo que vi, é o mesmo animal: os portugueses chamam-lhe *rato* e os brasileiros chamam-lhe *camundongo*, entre muitos outros nomes. Agora, não sei é por que é que no Brasil as pessoas gritam "rato". Mais rápido de dizer quando é preciso agir imediatamente? :)

Comment: Pelo menos no Sul do Brasil, e muito dificil usar camundongo. Usamos normalmente rato tbm...Sei que em Portugal, rata (rato no feminino tem outro sentido)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. [**Rato**](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rato) não denota uma espécie ou mesmo membros de uma dada família, é apenas um nome genérico para certos ([principalmente](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mouse#Types_of_animals_known_as_mice)) roedores pequenos.
2. [**Camundongo**](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mus_musculus) é uma espécie específica de roedor, a *Mus musculus*, também conhecida por nomes como *rato-doméstico* ([*house mouse*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_mouse)).
3. [**Ratazana**](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rattus_norvegicus) também denota uma espécie específica, maior, a *Rattus norvegicus* ([*common rat*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brown_rat)).

Portanto não é errado chamar um camundongo de rato e, coloquialmente, é mais provável de ser usado por pessoas com repulsa/medo do animal, especialmente quando se tratar de um exemplar maior. Como o Jacinto comenta, a palavra mais curta é também mais fácil e rápida de se falar. Às vezes, se vê "ratazana" ser usada também como sinônimo de "rato grande".

Em se tratando de nomes populares de animais e plantas, não se pode esperar muita consistência: um mesmo nome pode denotar diversas espécies diferentes e, com frequência, há uma infinidade de nomes diferentes para uma mesma espécie. Essa é uma dificuldade que só é multiplicada quando falamos de regionalismos e traduções.

Fora sites especializados, um bom lugar para se pesquisar sobre o assunto é a Wikipedia: embora às vezes checagens cruzadas (de links entre páginas em diferentes idiomas) revelem inconsistências, é pelo menos um bom começo. Para essa pergunta em específico, até os dicionários talvez já bastem: camundongo: [1](https://dicionario.priberam.org/camundongo), [2](http://www.aulete.com.br/camundongo); ratazana: [1](https://dicionario.priberam.org/ratazana), [2](http://www.aulete.com.br/ratazana); rato: [1](https://dicionario.priberam.org/rato), [2](http://www.aulete.com.br/rato).